# How to add a httpcontext.current to specflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, specflow

I have a method that retrieves the identity name from the httpcontext from the controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo()
{ 
    ...
    var userId = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    ...
}
```

My specflow test is failing because it cannot retrieve the Guid as there is no HttpContext. How can I set this up so that I can create specflow tests for this?

Comment: Avoid using `HttpContext.Current` in MVC and Web API projects. Instead you should be using the native web api constructs that are available in the `ApiController` like `RequestContext.Principal` which you can then mock in your tests.

Comment: @Igor That actually solved my problem. Thank you very much :)